# NodeJS inherits

Tags: node.js, inheritance

I've created some scripts and instantiated them on my main script

```
var eagle1 =new Fleet.F15c(456);
var eagle2 = new Fleet.F15c(123);
var falcon1 = new Fleet.F16(111);
var guardian1 = new Fleet.F14(789);
```

and have some functions

And now I wanna create a wing - so when the wing is ordered to do something, all the planes assigned to that wing will execute.
I created a 'wing command' script that should have 2 functions that will be called from the main script:

AssignCommand (orderName, planefunction) ->logs the plane function listener to the event emitter of that wing

ExecuteCommand (orderName) -> emits orderName

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(WingCommand,EventEmitter);
module.exports = WingCommand;

function WingCommand(){

}
```

But when I created the 1st func

```
WingCommand.prototype.AssignCommand = function (CommandName , PlaneFunc(data=null)){
    this.on(CommandName,PlaneFunc(data));
}
```

I did not manage figure out the unexpected token on this line

```
WingCommand.prototype.AssignCommand = function (CommandName , PlaneFunc(data=null)){
```

I tried some tutorials but did not find a solution
will appreciate your help

Comment: `PlaneFunc(data=null)` won't work with JS. The error message you get probably contains a line and column number, and that column number will most likely point at the open paren in `(data=null)`. Try to remove `(data=null)` and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks first of all

*folder path*\NodeJS\WingCommand.js:22
WingCommand.prototype.AssignCommand = function (CommandName , PlaneFunc(data)){
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (...
so line 22 is that line, even  after removing the =null

Comment: The (data) too ;-)

Comment: so how can i give data to the func? use another param?